# Python and BeautifulSoup error in encoding

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

Im getting error:

> File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0106' in
>   position 73: character maps to

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.privredni-imenik.com/firma/68225-a_expo'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"podaci"})
print(g_data)
```

How can i encode data in utf-8.
i have tried solutions from other topics, but none of them work for me.

Comment: do you have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the begging of your file?

Comment: Didnt have, i have just added it and its the same.

Comment: try `g_data.decode('utf_8')`

Comment: AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.privredni-imenik.com/firma/68225-a_expo'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"podaci"})
for i in g_data:
    some = i.text.encode('utf-8', 'replace')
    print (some)
```

It works, im receiving data but with weird characters.. Well thats question for another topic :)